# Removing all elements from HTML that have given class using Agility Pack

Tags: asp.net, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to select all elements that have a given class and remove them from a HTML string.

This is what I have so far it doesn't seem to remove anything although the source shows clearly 4 elements with that class name.

```
// Filter page HTML to display required content
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

// filePath is a path to a file containing the html
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(pageHTML);

// ParseErrors is an ArrayList containing any errors from the Load statement);
if (!htmlDoc.ParseErrors.Any())
{
    // Remove all elements marked with pdf-ignore class
    HtmlNodeCollection nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body[@class='pdf-ignore']");

    // Remove the collection from above
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        node.Remove();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Just to clarify the document is parsing and the SelectNodes line is being hit, just not returning anything.

Here is a snippet of the html:

```
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"ctl00$MainContent$PrintBtn\" value=\"Print Shotlist\" onclick=\"window.print();\" id=\"MainContent_PrintBtn\" class=\"pdf-ignore\">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** in your updated answer you posted a part of the HTML string an `<input>` element declaration, but you're trying to match a `<body>` element with the class `pdf-ignore` (according to your expression `//body[@class='pdf-ignore']`).

If you want to match all the elements from the document with this class you should use:

```
var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'pdf-ignore')]");
```

code to get your nodes. This will match all the elements with the class name specified.

Your code is seems to be correct except the one detail: the condition `htmlDoc.ParseErrors == null`. You  select and remove nodes ONLY if the `ParseErrors` property (which is a type of `IEnumerable<HtmlParseError>`) is `null`, but actually if no errors found this property returns an empty list. So changing your code to:

```
if (!htmlDoc.ParseErrors.Any())
{
    // some logic here
}
```

should solve the issue.

Comment: I had since noticed this actually, I've updated the question. It doesn't return any nodes though. My elements are in various positions within the document and I wish to remove them all. I've tried omitting the @ and it doesn't pick anything up still

Comment: @Andi, could you post your HTML string? Also in your updated question you use `htmlDoc.ParseErrors.Any()` condition which is `true` if there are at least one element in the collection (at least one error here).

Comment: @Andi, if you want to match any html element with this class use `//*[@class='pdf-ignore']` expression. In your updated answer you're trying to match a `<body>` tag with the class name specified.

Comment: I thought it would be something like that, thanks!! Pop that in your answer if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is probably not matching: have you tried `"//div[class='pdf-ignore']"`  (no `"@"`)?